# Google Sheets picks the wrong value in mobile when using a drop down with data validation

Tags: google-sheets

I have a shared Google Sheets file where dozens of users input data related to an online basketball game. One of the columns is a drop down list of basketball players built with data validation. The drop down works perfectly in the desktop version of the file but when it comes to mobile... users are unable to select the right player as Sheets automatically selects another one.

The use case is very specific. There are players with different versions such as:

N. Mirotic

N. Mirotic MVP

or

D. Musa

D. Musa JJ

When the user tries to select "N. Mirotic" in the dropdown, Sheets automatically changes it to "N. Mirotic MVP". This happens with other similar use cases where one of the values includes another + an additional string.

Again, this happens only in mobile, not desktop. But it always happens in mobile.

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Javier

Answer (score 1):

Never responded here before but I've had a similar error on the mobile app. I'm replying here on the off chance that my fix can in some way work with your issue and anyone else who may face a similar problem.

My Data Validation was a list of numbers from a range of cells on another sheet. These numbers ranged from 200-0. These were potential weights that could be selected. When I organised them from highest to lowest, I was getting an issue where if I tried to select 10, it would select 107.5. I couldn't make sense of this at all until I went on the desktop version and started to type '10' into the applicable cell. Now the list of all numbers beginned with '10' showed up and 107.5 was at the top of this list. Although it doesn't show you this, the mobile app under the hood seems to be treating your data validation as if it was being typed in the cell and the range of values shows up that it could potentially be, rather than you just selecting it off the list like you do on a desktop. The actions seem to be combined.

My simple fix was to organise the list values the opposite way, 0-200. Now when I test it on desktop and type '10', the values list in the same way; smallest to largest. So now when I select the numbers from the dropdown on the app it is selecting the first (now, the smallest) possible value from the list which will always be the one that is actually being selected from the dropdown.

With text like yours, the solution may be the ensure that all the 'non-MVP' names are listed first and then the list of names with 'MVP'. Hopefully now if someone selects a non-MVP name it actually selects it properly as it should show up first if you were to begin typing it on desktop.

Comment: I had a list from 10 to 0 with the same issue as you. Reversing the order from 0 to 10 fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: A function called Autocomplete is suggesting the other list item as predicted text, I'm trying to disable it on mobile.

Never responded here before but I've had a similar error on the mobile app. I'm replying here on the off chance that my facts can in some way assist anyone who may face a similar problem.

My Data Validation was a list of numbers, format 5.xx(-/ /+), from a range of cells on another sheet. These numbers ranged from 5.6 to 5.13+. These were difficulty grades of rock climbing routes that could be selected. When I organized them from lowest to highest (i.e. 5.10; 5.10+; 5.11-; 5.11; 5.11+), I was getting an issue where if I tried to select 5.12, it would select 5.12-. I only have the issue after the substituted selection has been selected in that cell previously, which is something I realized only after reading GNA_Matt's answer. The solution of reordering does not work for me (in reverse, 5.12 becomes 5.12+). However, the brilliant connection to predictive text led me to disable that function. Sheets calls it Autocomplete, and you can search the Sheets help to find and disable it.